# dynamically fill a json variable

Tags: javascript, php, json, charts, chart.js

I am trying to dynamically fill my chartjs with data from a database. 
The data is Volume specific (Letter and usage in percent).

Due to the flexibility of the database structure, i decided to put all volume informations in one single cell, which divides each volume with a whitespace and the letter and percentage with a comma.

Now i need to put this data dynamically inside a json variable so i can push it to my chart. At the moment it looks like this:

```
var jsonData = {
    "L": [{"y": 100}, {"y": 50}, {"y": 40}],
    "C": [{"y": 61}, {"y": 39}, {"y": 59}],
    "": [{"y": 33}, {"y": 97}, {"y": 67}]
}
```

But those values and volume letters are hardcoded. So i need to split up my php string, which includes the volumes, and somehow pass it for every entry to the json variable.

I need to select each letter **once**, and **every** value which belongs to the correspondending letter.

Also i should mention, that the json variable needs to be dynamically extendable because it is possible that there are more than 3 volumes per cell.

Comment: Does this problem not make you think it was a mistake to store the data like this?

Comment: @RiggsFolly That's invalid? But the chart actually works with this value. And yes i know it may not be the best way to store the data but it needs to be dynamically and  i can't make for every letter a new attribute inside the database. It is possible that there are more than 50 volumes.

Comment: @Adrian You don't need each letter to be an attribute. Dynamic data should be in column data, not column names.

Comment: Each volume and value should be a separate row in the table.

Comment: @RiggsFolly An empty string is a valid JSON object key. json.org says the key is a string, and "A string is a sequence of zero or more Unicode characters, wrapped in double quotes,"

Comment: Oh, well I stand corrected, thanks @Barmar I wont make that mistake again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this :

```
<?php

$data = array('L,100 C,61 ,31', 'L,50 C,39 ,97', ' L,40 C,59 ,67');
$result = array();
foreach($data as $key => $element){
    $parts = explode(" ",$element);
    foreach($parts as $part){
        $underParts = explode(',', $part);
        if(isset($underParts[0]) && isset($underParts[1]) ){
        $result[$underParts[0]][]=array('y'=>$underParts[1]);
        }


    }
}


var_dump(json_encode($result));
```

The result :

```
string(118) "{"L":[{"y":"100"},{"y":"50"},{"y":"40"}],"C":[{"y":"61"},{"y":"39"},{"y":"59"}],"":[{"y":"31"},{"y":"97"},{"y":"67"}]}"
```

Comment: You my friend, are a genius. This is exactly what i needed. Thanks!